# UCanAccess with JFileChooser: "Empty database file"

Tags: java, ms-access, jfilechooser, ucanaccess

I have my code set up so that the user can input a name for a Microsoft Access file, then the file is successfully created. However, I'd like to use JFileChooser to make the process smoother, but my code doesn't work when I use it.

Here is my (working) previous code, with some irrelevant code snipped out-

```
try {

    fileName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter file name ");
   String dbPath = "C:/Users/Evan/Documents/"+fileName+".accdb";

       System.out.println(dbPath);
       // outputs C:/Users/Evan/Documents/fileName.accdb
try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(

    "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbPath  
 +   ";newdatabaseversion=V2010"
)) {
 DatabaseMetaData dmd = conn.getMetaData();
    try (ResultSet rs = dmd.getTables(null, null, "Database", new String[] { "TABLE" })) {

        try (Statement s = conn.createStatement()) {
            s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + "Database " 
+" (Row COUNTER PRIMARY KEY, A DOUBLE , B DOUBLE)");
            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " created.");
            valueProperty.setValue(fileName);
        }

}
conn.close();

 }

}
 catch (Exception f){
  f.printStackTrace();
 }
       }
```

And here is the code I have now, that outputs an error of

> net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::4.0.2 Empty database file

and produces a file that does not and contains the error message "unrecognized database format" and the name and path of the file, despite the path of the file being identical to other working files excluding the file name:

```
try {

    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
   chooser.setCurrentDirectory(new File("/home/me/Documents"));
int retrieval = chooser.showSaveDialog(null);
if (retrieval == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
   FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".accdb");


  path=chooser.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()+".accdb";
 // System.out.println(path);
fileName=chooser.getSelectedFile().getName();

   String dbPath = path.replace("\\","/"); /* I know this looks weird, I
just did it because the output in the working version has it with / instead. 
I've tried it with both slashes and the result is the same. */   

   System.out.println(dbPath);
   // outputs C:/Users/Evan/Documents/fileName.accdb

/*where the code has an error */  try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(

    "jdbc:ucanaccess://" + dbPath  
 +   ";newdatabaseversion=V2010"
)) {
DatabaseMetaData dmd = conn.getMetaData();
    try (ResultSet rs = dmd.getTables(null, null, "Database", new String[] { 
"TABLE" })) {

        try (Statement s = conn.createStatement()) {
            s.executeUpdate("CREATE TABLE " + "Database" +" (Row COUNTER 
PRIMARY KEY, A DOUBLE , B DOUBLE)");
            System.out.println("File " + fileName + " created.");
            valueProperty.setValue(fileName);
        }

}
conn.close();

 }}
else 
    System.out.println("failed");
    return;

}
catch (Exception f){
  f.printStackTrace();
}
```

I'd appreciate any help anyone could offer, thanks

Comment: `;newdatabaseversion=V2010` will create a new file if it does not exist *at all*. If it exists, but contains zero bytes, then it is not a valid Access database. Trace your code to see if it is creating a zero-byte file, and if so then delete that file before trying to open your connection.

Comment: I deleted the `FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(chooser.getSelectedFile()+".accdb");` line and it works perfectly now, you were right about it making 0 bite files. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`;newdatabaseversion=V2010` will create a new file if it does not exist *at all*. If it exists, but contains zero bytes, then it is not a valid Access database. Trace your code to see if it is creating a zero-byte file, and if so then delete that file before trying to open your connection.